# generating function combinatorics solution

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I am studying generating functions in combinatorics, and came across a problem that has already been posted here:

[Generating function and combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/635041/generating-function-and-combinatorics)

> =x^10(1-x^6)^10 * (1+x+x^2....)^10

I simply don't understand why the answer to this is:

> C(10+15-1,15) - 10*C(10+9-1,9) + C(10,2)*C(10+3-1,3)

I can understand the first two combinations, but where did the C(10,2)*C(10+3-1,3) come from? I would appreciate any help to understand this. Thanks!

Comment: He just used the binomial theorem

Comment: I still don't understand. How was the binomial theorem used here to get to that?

Comment: I think if you look at the answers posted to this problem, you will see where this comes from.

Comment: In the first answer there, why is k=3 in the last combination?

Comment: He wants to find the coefficient of $x^{25}$ in $x^{10}(1-10x^6+45x^{12}-120x^{18}+210x^{24}-...)\big(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{9+k}{k}x^k\big)$

which is also the coefficient of $x^{15}$ in 

$(1-10x^6+45x^{12}-120x^{18}+210x^{24}-...)\big(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{9+k}{k}x^k\big)$

Note that, you have to consider only the first $3$ summands in the first parentheses, since the product with another summand would always give an exponent greater than $18$

Comment: For example the coefficient of $x^{15}$ in 

$-120x^{18}\big(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{9+k}{k}x^k\big)$ is zero, because here the smallest exponent of $x$ is $18$

Now how many summands are there ?

$1\cdot\binom{9+15}{15}x^{15}$ for $k=15$

$-10x^6\binom{9+9}{9}x^9=-10\binom{18}{9}x^{15}$ for $k=9$ 

$45x^{12}\binom{9+3}{3}x^3=45\binom{12}{3}x^{15}$ for $k=3$

Comment: Thank you so much OBDA! It finally clicked for me.